# Trying to access parent window element from child

Tags: javascript, dom, getelementbyid

I'm trying to access the parent window from a child. I'm using window.open()

I've been looking for a solution but nothing seems to work, I'm just trying to change some index form a select, but I can't get it to work.

```
<select id='mySelect></select>
```

The select it's populated dinamically, I'm not trying to change the selectedIndex before I append some options, so that's not the issue.

and this is the code I'm trying, so simple:

```
if (window.opener) {
    let select = window.opener.document.getElementById('mySelect')
    select.selectedIndex = 1
}
```

Some articles and answers I've seen are form a couple of years ago, the most recent ones I mean, so I'm wondering if I have to do it in other way or I'm just doing it wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I get the wording used. *Parent window element from child* is one thing, *selected index* is another thing - so it's unclear what you are asking

Comment: My select in on the parent window, so I'm trying to access the parent window with `window.opener.document` and get the element with `getElementById` and after it change it's index

Comment: Can you post full code. Because in above code I'm not seeing any issue except select tag does not having option at index 1

Comment: There's nothing relevant in the rest of the code, it is just the select which gets populated dinamically, and I don't try to change it's index untill it has some options, and the the code to change that index inside of a button. I've edited the post adding some more stuff, but I don't understand why it doesn't work